# My program just will not recognize letters from alphabetical arrays

Tags: arrays, c, search, cs50, alphabet

So this program won't recognize letters from the arrays of lowercase and uppercase alphabets. I've wasted wayy too many hours on trying to figure this out but I just don't get it.

It seems to recognize only 'a' or 'A' but even that not always.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>


char ALPHABETLower[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
char ALPHABETUpper[] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};


string plaintext = "abcdefghijklmnoprstquvwyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTQUVWXYZ";
int i;
int j;
                        

int main(void) {
    for(i = 0; plaintext[i] != 0; i++) {
        for(j = 0; plaintext[i] == ALPHABETUpper[j]; j++)
            printf("%c\n", ALPHABETUpper[j]);
                
        for(j = 0; plaintext[i] == ALPHABETLower[j]; j++)
            printf("%c\n", ALPHABETLower[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `plaintext[i] == ALPHABETUpper[j]` Revise what a `for` loop does. The condition in the loop causes the loop to exit as soon as the condition evaluates to false. So that loop will always exit immediately except for the case that `plaintext[i]` is the first letter in the `ALPHABETUpper` array.

Comment: @kaylum Oh wait I misread. Yeah that makes sense.

Comment: Not sure what other way you mean. But do a search for how other people have solved same/similar problem. There is a much cleverer way to do this such that you don't need the inner for loop. Anyway your code doesn't make sense if you are trying to encode the plaintext string because the encoded values are the same as the plaintext - that is `'a'` becomes `'a'`, `'b'` becomes `'b`', etc.

Comment: @kaylum I've cut out most of the code to leave only the relevant part. So far I've tried with "if" statements and a "while" loop and still nothing.

Comment: *So far I've tried with "if" statements and a "while" loop*. That doesn't tell us much as there are infinete ways to use if statements and while loops. As I said there is a better way to do this. `int c = tolower(plaintext[i]); int index = c - 'a'; char encodedC = ALPHABETLower[index];` That is, convert each plaintext character into an index and use that to get the encoded character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I wrestled through and this is the full working version. My mistake before was letting the for-loop run infinitely, unless it could find the character in ALPHABETUpper.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>


char ALPHABETLower[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
char ALPHABETUpper[] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};


string plaintext;
int i;
int j;


int main(int argc, string argv[2]) {
    for(i = 0; argv[1][i] != 0; i++)
        if(argv[1][i] < 48 || argv[1][i] > 57) {
            printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
            return 1;
        }    
    
    plaintext = get_string("Plaintext: \n");

    for(i = 0; plaintext[i] != 0; i++) {
        if(isalpha(plaintext[i]) == 0)
                printf("%c", plaintext[i]);
                
        for(j = 0; j < 26; j++) {

            if(plaintext[i] == ALPHABETUpper[j])
                printf("%c", ALPHABETUpper[(j + atoi(argv[1])) % 26]);
                    
            if(plaintext[i] == ALPHABETLower[j])
                printf("%c", ALPHABETLower[(j + atoi(argv[1])) % 26]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: regarding: `int main(int argc, string argv[2]) {`  this is invalid

Comment: How is it invalid tho? That's the one part I did 100% as required, and besides, it works as intended nontheless? @user3629249

Comment: how is it invalid?  simple, the second parameter is (per the C standard) is a pointer to an array of pointers, NOT a fixed sized array And the array ends with a NULL pointer,  So if the total number of array elements is 2, then the array only has room for the pointer to the executable name, followed by a NULL pointer

Comment: there are only two valid signatures for `main()`..  They are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char * argv[] )`

Comment: You know, I'm not quite sure why there's a 2 in the brackets. As I understand, if it's limited to two, then there's only room for pointing out which of the command line arguments to select for the array, and also a signal for when the array ends, without actually the contents of the array itself? Or for that matter anything else (eg other arrays)?

Either way yes, that must've been a typo on my part. Thanks for pointing out @user3629249

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I think you only need the to include `stdio.h` in your program.

Then you have `string plainText = "...";`, but you should have `char* plainText = "...";`, because that's the way you make strings in C language (I dont know if all those libraries you have are for making that `string` variable, but the easiest and correct way to make a string is like I did, with `char`).

So you then have in your first `for` loop `i = 0; plaintext[i] != 0; i++` so you can stop when the string is over, but I dont think that really works, the best way you can do it is `i = 0; i < 52; i++`.

You have another problem in the others `for` loops. You are trying to make a conditional statement in a `for` loop and I dont think that's even possible to do (in `while` loops you can). So maybe those for loops should look like:

```c
#define MaxLetters 52
#define AlphabetLetters 26

(. . .)

int main(void)
{
    (. . .)

    for(i = 0; i < MaxLetters; i++) {    //52 letters in total on plainText string
        for(j = 0; j < AlphabetLetters; j++)    //26 letters in total on ALPHABETUpper
        {
            if(plainText[i] == ALPHABETUpper[j])        
                printf("%c\n", ALPHABETUpper[j]);
        }
        
        for(j = 0; j < AlphabetLetters; j++)    //26 letters in total on ALPHABETLower
        {
            if(plainText[i] == ALPHABETLower[j])        
                printf("%c\n", ALPHABETLower[j]);
        }
    
    (. . .)
}
```